# Formula Field Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: formula

```
IF(
    $RecordType.Name = "Protective Account",
    "Agency Name:  Name  " &
    "     Location: " &
    ShippingStreet & 
    " " &  
    ShippingCity & 
    ", " & 
    ShippingState & 
    " " &  
    ShippingPostalCode & 
    "     Phone: " &
    Phone
    , 
    "Agency Number: " &  
    "[" & Name 
    BLANKVALUE( Agent_ID__c , "-") &
    "][" &
    BLANKVALUE( PGR_Code__c, "-") & 
    "]" &
    "     Location: " &
    ShippingStreet & 
    " " &  
    ShippingCity & 
    ", " & 
    ShippingState & 
    " " &  
    ShippingPostalCode & 
    "     Phone: " &
    Phone
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  [`IF()`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_if.htm&type=5) requires 3 parameters, you are missing the last one.

Comment: @DavidCheng There are 3 parameters here (the second comma is between "Phone" and "Agent Number"). All of the concatenation being done does make it hard to see though.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is a bit misleading in this case.

After staring at this for a while, the main issue is actually that you missed a concatenation in the "else" part.

```java
"Agency Number: " &  
/* You are missing an & operator after "Name" */
"[" & Name
BLANKVALUE( Agent_ID__c , "-") &
```

The syntax checker seems to be (incorrectly) interpreting that as "Name is the end of the IF(), so there should be a `)` here", hence the error being reported.

You also have a semantic error in `"Agency Name:  Name  " &`, which I'd guess should be `"Agency Name: " & Name &`

While fixing those two things should get you going, there is more work that could (should?) be done with this formula. The ShippingAddress + Phone parts are exactly the same in both of the branches of the `IF()`, so they can be extracted to make the formula shorter.

The end result would look like

```
IF(
    $RecordType.Name = "Protective Account",
    "Agency Name:  " & Name, 
    "Agency Number: " &  "[" & Name & BLANKVALUE( Agent_ID__c , "-") & "]"
        & "[" & BLANKVALUE( PGR_Code__c, "-") & "]"
)
& "     Location: " & ShippingStreet & " " &  ShippingCity & ", " 
& ShippingState & " " &  ShippingPostalCode & "     Phone: " & Phone
```

The formatting choices I made above are not critical. Just trying to keep things readable (and lines short enough so that you don't need to scroll horizontally).